# Mass mail sending from linux

Tags: php, linux, bash, amazon-ec2, sendmail

i've been running a website for the last years which have grow up significally. Right now in my database i have about 40k emails and i'm planning to send emails to those people which get subcrived to some sort of feeds. The idea is to be able to email to everyone who gets subscribed.

As for now i've been trying with phplist, to read the emails and send send them but i find it to take so much time to send all the emails.

- First of all i would like to know if there is out there any web list where i have to subscrive my domain in order to let gmail, hotmail, yahoo, etc know that i'm not spam and i'm going to send "lots" of emails in a dayly/weekly basis?
- The other question is, is there any better way to send the emails in a short time? I've been thinking on things like, run a cronjob which send emails at the same time to people whose email starts by letter a, b, c, d, e, etc so i could send emails on parallel but i don't know if that's a good idea. Another thing i've tought is to create a linux user for every user and run a cronjob for every user, all at same time, which send the email to the corresponding email.

I don't know if that's the way to go so i appreaciate any kind of help or suggestions. Thank you so much! :)

PD: I would like to be able to send the emails in an average of 30-40minutes and also make hotmail, gmail, yahoo, etc to not classify me as spam. Right now i'm using an Amazon free EC2 account with just one AMI instance but i could pay for the any other service or extra instance i need in order to get the job done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A couple problems re: CodeIgniter emailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038465/a-couple-problems-re-codeigniter-emailer)

Answer (score 2):

Use Amazon's email solution:  http://aws.amazon.com/ses/  ... otherwise, sending out massive amounts of "email", irrespective of how you classify it (spam or not) is generally not a great thing to do from a **free** instance.

Other people will surely recommend other services like http://mailchimp.com/ which are also quite fit for purpose ...

Finally, if you are stubborn, don't want to pay for a service that does it, you can look at deploying a few MTA's (Mail Transfer Agent) that are well tuned and properly configured to ensure that they are sending maximum amounts of emails in a limited amount of time.  You can use cron as you suggest, or some enterprise scheduling tool, like `TWS`, to help orchestrate this.

To be honest ... if you don't go with the first two approaches, and attempt to legitimate your purpose by leveraging **free** ... i would be inclined to classify you as spam.  If you go the right way ... you will do things properly and pay for some services which help to guarantee you aren't a spammer...

Comment: Okay so only other people decide whether you're a spammer or not? What's that for a sort of logic? I can understand being reserved when it comes to mass-mailing, but actually it's a bit harsh to think so.

Comment: I read:  daily * (40k users / split by a/b/c/d/etc. every 30-40min) on a single **free** ec2 micro instance from amazon == spam ... harsh?  perhaps.  i'll judge when i receive the first email i didn't "opt-in" for

Answer (score 0):

I've voted to close this as a duplicate of the many questions asked and answered here and on stackoverflow of how to avoid being detected as SPAM - but looking through them, there's a paucity of good answers.

There is no white list of senders.

Yes, massaging your queues will help with deliverability.

There's some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038465/a-couple-problems-re-codeigniter-emailer/) however you need to be aware that bulk-emailing is a very complex issue. While I could talk about SPF, R-MX, correct PTR records and mod_throttle, the best advice is probably to go talk to a **reputable** provider who specialises in the field - and set up some hotmail and gmail addresses so you can monitor the service yourself.